# Public ObservableCollection causing crashes

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Whenever I make an ObservableCollection a public variable, as soon as the page is called with it on it the app crashes. What I'm trying to do is Add items to the public ObservableCollection from another class... I'll try to represent the structure below

Dir: Project/Class/PrepareSpells.xaml

```
public ObservableCollection<PublicVariables.Spell> level0 = new ObservableCollection<PublicVariables.Spell>();
```

Dir: Project/SpellLists/PopulateList.cs

```
Class.PrepareSpells prepare = new Class.PrepareSpells();

PublicVariables.Spell newSpell = new PublicVariables.Spell();
newSpell.spellLevel = 0;
newSpell.spellName = zeroName[i];
prepare.level0.Add(newSpell);
```

Please note that PopulateList is contained within a valid 'for' loop. I have also created an object for the PrepareSpells.xaml (prepare, above).

Is there a different way to do this or is it impossible? If I simply have an OC in the PopulateList whenever I manipulate it further (ie, to populate a higher spell level list) it modifies ALL the OC's in the PrepareSpells.xaml domain to reflect the new changes.

Please let me know if this is far too ambiguous and I will provide more code.

Comment: Please explain or show code that executes "as soon as the page is called". Is it the constructor that is crashing?

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, then everything should work perfectly so we are going to need more information to solve your problem. Find the exact line of code that the app crashes on and let us know what that is.

Comment: What exception is being thrown? What is the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue: I was inputting invalid data... I feel sheepish....